# String expected Error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fernando {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner skype = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your name ")?
        String n = skype.nextLine(); // This is the line with the error
        System.out.print("\n and how old are you?");
        int y = skype.nextInt();
        displayInfo(n,y);
    }

    public String displayInfo(String name, int age){
        return name +" is "+ age+" years old.";
    }
}
```

All it says is expected. I don't understand what's wrong at all.

Comment: What is expected? Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: The whole error is "expected"?

Comment: @ArturMalinowski Wrong, Java allows such a concatenation.

Comment: `System.out.print("What is your name ")?`...you mean, `System.out.print("What is your name ?");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
System.out.print("What is your name ")?
```

to:

```
System.out.println("What is your name?");
```

This should work, as you have a ? instead of a ;.